# How can I integrate user input (using Scanner) into a while Loop for calculating the 1+2+3+....n where n is any positive integer?

Tags: java

I'm having trouble solving part 1b from this problem.

1a. Write a program called CountLoop.java that contains a main method with a loop that will compute and print the sum of all the integers between 1 and 100, inclusive. Execute your program to verify that the output is correct."

```
public class CountLoop{
   public static void main(String[] args){
       int sum = 0; 
       int i = 0;       // i is 0 Here

       while (i<=100) {
        sum += i; 
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
 }
}
```

1b. After you have the program working, refactor it so you can compute 1 + 2 + … + n where n is any positive integer. In other words, your revised program should prompt the user to enter a number, read the user input, calculate the sum of the integers from 1 to the input value, and output the sum.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class CountLoop{
        public static void main(String[] args){
            System.out.println("Please enter a positive whole number");
            Scanner inPut = new Scanner(System.in);
            int sum = 0;
            int i = 0;
            int userInput = inPut.nextInt(); 
            while (i<=userInput){
                sum += i;
                i++;

            System.out.println("Sum of this number: " + inPut.nextInt() + " is " + sum);
        }   
 }
}
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Javascript. You should try to work on learning the name of the language you're attempting to write code in, and tag your questions appropriately.

Comment: You are mis-reading the requirements. You only need to prompt once for the number to keep adding until.  `System.out.println("Sum of this number: " + inPut.nextInt() + " is " + sum);` will try to read another number from the user

Comment: How about [`int sum = (n + 1)*n/2;`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF)?

Comment: I guess I should rephrase my question. Lets say that the user input number 10 into the program, how can I create a while loop that can calculate the total sum value from 1 to the input value?

Answer (score 1):

Basically in your while loop print statement you are again and again looking for the input, which is not required :

> System.out.println("Sum of this number: " + inPut.nextInt() + " is "
>   + sum);

As per question you simply need the user to enter and number n  and then you need to return the sum of numbers between 1-N(including 1 and n).

You just need to print the total sum, so move the print out of the loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
            System.out.println("Please enter a positive whole number");
            Scanner inPut = new Scanner(System.in);
            int sum = 0;
            int i = 0;
            int userInput = inPut.nextInt(); 
            while (i<= userInput){
                sum += i;
                i++;
            }
          System.out.println("Sum : " + sum);
    }
```

And it is better to simple simple mathematical formula of `sum of first n natural numbers` rather than using while loop if the question has not asked to do so.

Comment: I think it is important to point out for the OP that he (I assume) mistakenly prompts for a new input while printing the result. That oversight is his acutual problem, IMO. Also, the assignment specifically asks for a loop, the gaussian formula is not needed

Comment: @king_nak Thanks a lot. updated the answer based on your comments.